# remove trailing slash from specific url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

how to redirect trailing slash from specific URL,

for example:

```
http://blabla.com/builders/anynumber1/anynumber2/anynumber3/London(any country)/
```

to

```
http://blabla.com/builders/anynumber1/anynumber2/anynumber3/London(any country)
```

Comment: [`rtrim($url, PATH_SEPARATOR);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)  for [htaccess solution](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[^/]+)/$ /$1
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[^/]+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

EDIT:
You'll need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[^/]+)/.+$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Hey, it's worked, can you answer to one more question, so i can choose you as a best answer, what if i add http://blabla.com/builders/anynumber1/anynumber2/anynumber3/London(any country)/(Random letters) i want to 404 error random letters

Comment: @user3121594 technically unrelated to your question, but see edit